# MDF/MAC emissions and policies

Tags: environmental-economics

Bear with me - this is a long question. But I did do few of the parts, but I'm posting it because it seems necessary that you know what I previously did. Sorry for the "length"! Answers are given in blockquotes.

MAC = Marginal Abatement Cost MDF = Marginal Damage Function

1) A policy maker is faced with the following MDF from the emissions of nitrous oxide: MDF = 1000 E (where E = tons of emissions). Research leads the policy maker to perceive that the industry MAC function is MAC = 130,000 – 1000E.

a) What will be the perceived economically efficient target of emissions?

> Efficient target would be the situation where 
>   MDF = MAC
>   | 1000E = 130,000 – 1000E
>
> E = 65

b) What is the emissions fee that generates that target?

> Emission fee = MDF = 1,000E = 1,000 × 65 = 65,000

c) What is the aggregate level of permits that generates that target?

> Aggregate level of permit = MDF × E = 65,000 × 65 = 4,225,000

d) If there is a thick market for permits, what will be the market price of a permit?

e)The actual MAC is MAC = 150,000 – 500E. Find or show the cost of an error from using an emission fee.

f) The actual MAC is MAC = 150,000 – 500E. Find or show the cost of an error from using cap and trade.

Could someone help me figure out on how to do part d, e and f?

Comment: Please consider defining the acronyms MDF and MAC.

Comment: I apologize, I have correctly defined the terms.